# grails v3.0.0.M1 - I can create a script, but not sure how to run it

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I started trying to have a peek at grails v3.0.0.M1.

I unpacked and setup and created an app

When creating a script by using folowing command

```
  grails create-script my-script
```

it creates a script and drops the hyphen - so script is myscript.groovy.  Thought it might camel case that. More importantly - how do you run it?

In the grails command line prompt when I go help - the new script is not visible. If you try `grails> my-script`, it fails with

```
Error command not found my-script...
```

Having created a script - how do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Given a script named `myscript.groovy`, run it as

```
grails myscript
```

I haven't looked at the code, but it seems like a bug that it's dropping the hyphen. You should create an issue at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS/. It's easy to fix though, just rename the file to `my-script.groovy` and then you can run

```
grails my-script
```

Comment: Looks like issue tracking has moved to: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues